# Combinations with restrictions in R

Tags: r

How to get all `combinations(9,2)` with the following restrictions:
`n1 > 2`,
`n2 < 7`,
`n1 + n2 < 11`.
There are 5 combinations in result: `3 4`, `3 5`, `3 6`, `4 5`, `4 6`?

Comment: (1) What library are you using? `combinations` is not a base R function. (2) What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 3):

Or without any `apply` function

```r
comb <- t(combn(9,2))

comb[comb[, 1] > 2 & comb[, 2] < 7 & comb[, 1] + comb[, 2] < 11, ]
```

Comment: As someone who posted an `apply` answer I like this alternative a lot. I assume it's probably very efficient as well, not only in loc but in speed as well. Not that the latter mattered in this concrete use case. +1

Answer (score 2):

I did this:

```
library(gtools)
a= combinations(9,2)
a =apply(a, 1, function(i){
  if(i[1]>2&i[2]<7&(i[1]+i[2])<11){return(i)}
})
a= matrix(unlist(a), ncol = 2,byrow = T)
```

the output:

```
>a
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    3    4
[2,]    3    5
[3,]    3    6
[4,]    4    5
[5,]    4    6
```

Let me know if it was what you wanted

Answer (score 2):

To find all those combinations I use `combn` which comes as standard with R and does not need any additional packages.

For filtering I use `apply` with an anonymous filtering function and which to find which combinations fullfill the filter criterion:

```
comb <- combn(9,2)

n <- apply(comb, 2, \(x) x[1] > 2 & x[2] < 7 & sum(x) < 11) |> 
         which()
comb[, n]
```

will yield

```
>  comb[, n]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    3    3    3    4    4
[2,]    4    5    6    5    6
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the code below

```
Filter(
  length,
  combn(9,
    2,
    FUN = function(x) if (x[1] > 2 & x[2] < 7 & sum(x) < 11) list(x) else list(NULL)
  )
)
```

which gives

```
[[1]]
[1] 3 4

[[2]]
[1] 3 5

[[3]]
[1] 3 6

[[4]]
[1] 4 5

[[5]]
[1] 4 6
```